# Page rotation problem when using package {pdfpages}

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

When using pdfpages with revtex, all pages in the original document change from portrait to landscape upon simply including the package via \usepackage{pdfpages}. This is a MWE illustrating the issue:

```latex
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

This issue does not occur with \documentclass{article}.

Comment: Welcome to this site.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that to better understand what is expected in this community.

Comment: You should show a complete example, starting with \documentclass.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample MWE (minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-, landscape=true, angle=270}]{foo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Which shows a couple of the options that might solve your issue. You can also look [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) for the CTAN page of pdfpages which goes into much details about usage and options.

Comment: The problem is before I use \includepdf
even without including, the pdf outcome is shifted in 90 degrees

Comment: +1: Please extend your code to be a compilable mwe.

Comment: It is as above, I'm not sure why, even without \includepdf (I checked), when I ran the code, The outcome PDF is rotated by 90 degrees...

Comment: @jonathan Then just rotate it back (within laTeX) or correct the orientation outside of LaTeX (using some PDF viewer that can change the orientation or using ImageMagick for example).